# How can I show YouTube video link get from database in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube

I have this class which handle the data comes from future function :

```
Class MyYoutube {
    final int index ;
    final String link; // youtube Link
  MyYoutube(this.index , this.link); }
```

to get this link i have this page which used Future function :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';
class VideoPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VideoPlayerState createState() => _VideoPlayerState();
}
class _VideoPlayerState extends State<VideoPlayer> {
  YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: '',
      flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
        autoPlay: false,
        mute: false,
      ));
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<List> MyVideo() async {
      var url = ' 10.0.0.2/api/link.php';
      var respons = http.get(url);
      var data = jsonDecode(respons.body);
      for (var x in data) {
        MyYoutube newvideo = MyYoutube(x['index'], x['title_k'], x['title_a'],
            x['aya'], x['link'], x['activity_k'], x['activity_a'], x['act_id']);
        video.add(newvideo);
      }
      return video;
    }
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      child: YoutubePlayer(
        controller: _controller,
        showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
        progressIndicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

The problem is how to use the link get from future in YouTube controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot ,I solved it my self ,I moved Video Player Controller inside the future builder and set the value of initial Video Id as link get form database.

```
 return FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchDigrees(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          Map rdata = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
          var lang = rdata['lang'];
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Center(
              child: Text("Loading"),
            );
          } else {
            YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
                initialVideoId: snapshot.data[0].link,
                flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
                  autoPlay: false,
                  mute: false,
                ));
            return Container(
```

the show the video player and it is worked correctly

```
YoutubePlayer(
                        controller: _controller,
                        showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
                        progressIndicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                      ),
```